# create buttons on onclick function while getting values from textboxes for their rows and columns

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
    <header>        
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="table"  id="div1" >         
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="boxes" id="boxes">
            <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="value" id='value' />
            <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="value2" id='value2' />
            <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="size()" />
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

So basically when i write this `window.onload = function() {beggining1(10,10);};`

everything works ok, when page loads 10 rows and 10 columns of buttons are made. 
But now i want instead on pageload ,I want to make the buttons from a button which recieves columns and rows properties from 2 text boxes.`<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="size()" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rows = getElementById('value');
    var columns = getElementById('value2');
    window.onload = function() {beggining1(10,10);};

    function size(){
        beggining1(rows,columns);       
    }


    function beggining1(k,l){   
        for (i=1;i<k;i++){
            for (j=1;j<l;j++){
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                btn.className = "button1";  
                btn.style.cssText = 'background:green;height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
                var t = document.createTextNode(i+"_"+j);
                btn.appendChild(t);             
                document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(btn);
                document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click' , reserve);

            }           
            document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

I dont know whats wrong in my code and im trying to understand but i can't i guess its something stupid i miss.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `size` function with the updated one mentioned below and remove `window.load` handler as now you want to generate when user click on button,
I return false from the `size()` function because if the button is in `form` tag it would submit the form and postback the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function size(){

        var rows = document.getElementById("value").value;
        var columns = document.getElementById("value2").value;

        beggining1(rows,columns);
        return false;
    }


    function beggining1(k,l){   
        for (i=1;i<k;i++){
            for (j=1;j<l;j++){
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                btn.className = "button1";  
                btn.style.cssText = 'background:green;height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
                var t = document.createTextNode(i+"_"+j);
                btn.appendChild(t);             
                document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(btn);
                document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click' , reserve);

            }           
            document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: it does not work , can you tell me what "return false;" is doing but anyways it does not work when i delete the window.onload

Comment: @Arch_interpreter answer updated, if it not works show me the error in console.

Comment: well yea when i tested i deleted the window.load handler cuz i want to generate the whole thing on button click not when page loads , im using notepad++ how can i look at errors :D

Comment: i don't get any errors just when i fill the boxes and press the button nothing happens